# winapi startservice generate error 1058 for w32Time service

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I was running the sample provided by MS.
[Starting a Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/starting-a-service)

I use Windows 10 21H2.

I did it in the order below

---

First, I disable 'control panel' > 'date and time' > 'Synchronization with internet time' and click 'OK'
[disable Synchronization with internet time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN3Nc.png)

Second, I execute My code (My full code is below)
Then, error 1058
(The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.. )
[result error 1058](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cUWI.png)

---

If I enable 'Synchronization with internet time' again, the code works fine...

I don't know why this 1058 error occurs.

I've been searching for days, but I can't figure out the cause.

However, it is thought that the startservice api does not operate when the service is stopped.

I wonder if this is correct?

Thank you.

---

Add 21:30 minutes.

I found that startservice throws 1058 error if start type is disabled in services.msc.
I would like to know additionally whether the user program cannot automatically or manually change the disabled service.

---

My full code is below.

```
// servicetest.cpp : 이 파일에는 'main' 함수가 포함됩니다. 거기서 프로그램 실행이 시작되고 종료됩니다.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

VOID __stdcall DoStartSvc(LPCWSTR szSvcName);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    const WCHAR *name = L"w32Time";
    DoStartSvc(name);
}

VOID __stdcall DoStartSvc(LPCWSTR szSvcName)
{
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssStatus;
    DWORD dwOldCheckPoint;
    DWORD dwStartTickCount;
    DWORD dwWaitTime;
    DWORD dwBytesNeeded;

    // Get a handle to the SCM database. 

    SC_HANDLE schSCManager = OpenSCManager(
        NULL,                    // local computer
        NULL,                    // servicesActive database 
        SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access rights 

    if (NULL == schSCManager)
    {
        printf("OpenSCManager failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Get a handle to the service.

    SC_HANDLE schService = OpenService(
        schSCManager,         // SCM database 
        szSvcName,            // name of service 
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access 

    if (schService == NULL)
    {
        printf("OpenService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }

    // Check the status in case the service is not stopped. 

    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
        schService,                     // handle to service 
        SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
        (LPBYTE)&ssStatus,             // address of structure
        sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
        &dwBytesNeeded))              // size needed if buffer is too small
    {
        printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }

    // Check if the service is already running. It would be possible 
    // to stop the service here, but for simplicity this example just returns. 

    if (ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED && ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    {
        printf("Cannot start the service because it is already running\n");
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }

    // Save the tick count and initial checkpoint.

    dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
    dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;

    // Wait for the service to stop before attempting to start it.

    while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    {
        // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is 
        // one-tenth of the wait hint but not less than 1 second  
        // and not more than 10 seconds. 

        dwWaitTime = ssStatus.dwWaitHint / 10;

        if (dwWaitTime < 1000)
            dwWaitTime = 1000;
        else if (dwWaitTime > 10000)
            dwWaitTime = 10000;

        Sleep(dwWaitTime);

        // Check the status until the service is no longer stop pending. 

        if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
            schService,                     // handle to service 
            SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
            (LPBYTE)&ssStatus,             // address of structure
            sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
            &dwBytesNeeded))              // size needed if buffer is too small
        {
            printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            CloseServiceHandle(schService);
            CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
            return;
        }

        if (ssStatus.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint)
        {
            // Continue to wait and check.

            dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
            dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;
        }
        else
        {
            if (GetTickCount() - dwStartTickCount > ssStatus.dwWaitHint)
            {
                printf("Timeout waiting for service to stop\n");
                CloseServiceHandle(schService);
                CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Attempt to start the service.

    if (!StartService(
        schService,  // handle to service 
        0,           // number of arguments 
        NULL))      // no arguments 
    {
        printf("StartService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }
    else printf("Service start pending...\n");

    // Check the status until the service is no longer start pending. 

    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
        schService,                     // handle to service 
        SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // info level
        (LPBYTE)&ssStatus,             // address of structure
        sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
        &dwBytesNeeded))              // if buffer too small
    {
        printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }

    // Save the tick count and initial checkpoint.

    dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
    dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;

    while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_START_PENDING)
    {
        // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is 
        // one-tenth the wait hint, but no less than 1 second and no 
        // more than 10 seconds. 

        dwWaitTime = ssStatus.dwWaitHint / 10;

        if (dwWaitTime < 1000)
            dwWaitTime = 1000;
        else if (dwWaitTime > 10000)
            dwWaitTime = 10000;

        Sleep(dwWaitTime);

        // Check the status again. 

        if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
            schService,             // handle to service 
            SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, // info level
            (LPBYTE)&ssStatus,             // address of structure
            sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
            &dwBytesNeeded))              // if buffer too small
        {
            printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }

        if (ssStatus.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint)
        {
            // Continue to wait and check.

            dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
            dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;
        }
        else
        {
            if (GetTickCount() - dwStartTickCount > ssStatus.dwWaitHint)
            {
                // No progress made within the wait hint.
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Determine whether the service is running.

    if (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
    {
        printf("Service started successfully.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Service not started. \n");
        printf("  Current State: %d\n", ssStatus.dwCurrentState);
        printf("  Exit Code: %d\n", ssStatus.dwWin32ExitCode);
        printf("  Check Point: %d\n", ssStatus.dwCheckPoint);
        printf("  Wait Hint: %d\n", ssStatus.dwWaitHint);
    }

    CloseServiceHandle(schService);
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this
[changing-a-service-configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/changing-a-service-configuration)

I don't know why I haven't seen it until now.

If error 1058 occurs, change the startup type by calling ChangeServiceConfig and calling startservice again, it works properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).